# How to show the full placeholder text in an ios UITextfield?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout, interface-builder

The placeholder text does show the triple points to cut off the text.

The text doesn't even take half of the textfield width, and the three points are longer than the text. Is there a way to go inside the field and adjust the threshold to avoid the cutoff?

I do know the programatic way, and use that for the moment, to resize the placeholder tekst, till it fits.

```
    let labelKeyPath: String = "_placeholderLabel"
    var label : UILabel = self.Distance.value(forKeyPath: labelKeyPath) as! UILabel
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label = self.FocalLength.value(forKeyPath: labelKeyPath) as! UILabel
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Herby I do add some images of the current IB settings and results. Please keep adding points to let me show the current and future images embedded, thank you.

[The IB view, settings and app result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spy3C.png)

Comment: just change the width of the textfield and you will get the expected output. The placeholder trims as the width of textfield is not as expected to fit the palceholder

Comment: Why should I widen the textfield, it is already too big for the value. The issue is that the result is bigger than the placeholder and that fits nicely, so why not the placeholder? Also why are the three dots wider then the one letter that I need here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative you can create your own UITF subclass and override:

```
open func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I did move the origin a few pixels too.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the textfield to fix you issue. put this CustomTextField in your Storyboard textfield class type. here am setting minimum scaling factor to 0.3. that helps to fix the ...

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        for subview in subviews {
            if let label = subview as? UILabel {
                label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.3
                label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can adjust minimumScaleFactor for you desired value.

Answer (score 0):

You should change **Autolayouts Constraints** with **leading**, **center vertically** with Distance and **horizontal space** with the Distance.

You can also wrap up text with resize the textfield using **minimum font size**.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure how this fix it with this. My Row with fields are in a StackView. Just to understand it better what you mean, can you with the above text explain how it should work and the expected result?

Comment: You should set textfield's Autolayouts Constraints Leading : 0, Center vertically of View, Top: 0 and Bottom:0.

As well as you can change minimum font size of UITextField for wrap into textFiled.

Comment: I understand now what you wrote. thank you. I did try before the zeroing the constraints but not together with the font size.